# How to freeze columns in PrimeNg data table - Angular 2?

Tags: angular, datatables, primeng

In PrimeNg data table , is it possible to freeze first few columns and have horizontal scroll-x for the rest ?
I want exactly similar to this :

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/two_columns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p-dataTable [value]="..yoursource" [frozenWidth]="Set your frozen width in px" [unfrozenWidth]="Set your un frozen width in px">

    -- frozen column
    <p-column [header]="" [frozen]="true">
      <template>                      
      </template>
    </p-column>

   --unfrozen column
    <p-column>
    <p-column>

</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will enable frozen column with horizontal and vertical scrolling

In horizontal scrolling it is important to give fixed widths to columns. In general when customizing the column widths of scrollable tables, use colgroup as below to avoid misalignment issues as it will apply both the header, body and footer sections which are different separate elements internally.

HTML Temple

```
<p-table [columns]="scrollableCols" [frozenColumns]="frozenCols" [value]="data" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="500px" frozenWidth="250px">
    <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
        <colgroup>
            <col *ngFor="let col of columns" [style.width.px]="col.width">
        </colgroup>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

TS Code

```
frozenCols: any[];

scrollableCols: any[];

ngOnInit() {

    this.scrollableCols = [
        { field: 'year', header: 'Year', width: 250 },
        { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand', width: 250 },
        { field: 'color', header: 'Color', width: 250 },
        { field: 'year', header: 'Year', width: 250 },
        { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand', width: 250 },
        { field: 'color', header: 'Color', width: 250 }
    ];

    this.frozenCols = [
        { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin', width: 250 }
    ];

}
```

[Check here for more](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/scroll)